# Cómo manejar el "String or binary data would be truncated" - SQL - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Tengo una aplicación [ASP.NET MVC](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc) con SQL y el framework [NHibernate](https://nhibernate.info/) y debo atacar el problema *"String or binary data would be truncated"* que se da cuando intento almacenar más caracteres de los que soporta el campo de la tabla.

El caso sería este:

### Definición de la clase:

```
public class Entidad
{
    private string _unaPropiedad;

    public Entidad()
    {
    }

    public string UnaPropiedad
    {
        get { return _unaPropiedad; }
        set { _unaPropiedad = value; }
    }
}
```

### Mapping de NHibernate:

```
<class name="Entidad" table="Entidad">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid.comb"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="UnaPropiedad"/>
</class>
```

### SQL (es un campo varchar de 250 que permite valores nulos):

```
UnaPropiedad (varchar(250), null)
```

El problema se da cuando se asignan más de 250 caracteres a la propiedad *UnaPropiedad* lo cuál es posible, pero al momento de persistir esta información en SQL obtengo la excepción mencionada.

El tema es que quiero conocer soluciones genéricas para esto más allá de controlarlo en cada propiedad así que les consulto:

¿Cuenta NHibernate con algo para controlar esto?

Me gustaría conocer qué opciones hay para atacar este problema.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Considera incluir el código que estas utilizando para poder entender mejor la forma en que estas trabajando

Comment: Gracias Paulo, pasa que es más un tema general, pero ahora veo de agregarlo!

Answer (score 1):

Esta situación trasciende a NHibernate, sucede con cualquier tecnología de acceso a datos. Al poner un límite en SQL Server, este lanzará un error si intentas guardar algo más largo.

Hay varias soluciones para esto:

- Si realmente esperas que el usuario pueda ingresar más de 250 caracteres, puedes incrementar el valor. No sabes cuanto? En este caso puedes cambiar el tamaño de la columna a text (o ntext si precisas almacenar texto unicode).
- Para la mayoría de los campos queremos asignar límites, para eso lo que debes hacer es poner validaciones e indicar un error al usuario. Por ejemplo, si un campo es requerido por la base de datos, debes validar que el campo sea ingresado por el usuario, este caso es igual, el campo tiene un largo máximo, debes validarlo antes de intentar guardarlo.

Recuerda, el largo máximo de un campo es únicamente una validación, y las validaciones suelen hacerse en varios lugares. Se hacen del lado del cliente (típicamente con javascript), del lado del backend (en tu código que corre en el servidor) y finalmente algunas se hacen en la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias Juan por la respuesta. La solución particular la vengo aplicando sin problemas, pero mi pregunta está orientada a soluciones más generales que no impliquen crear la validación específica por cada campo/propiedad nuevo que tenga estas características.

Comment: No hay una solución general, tu decisión se debe tomar basándote en necesidades de negocio básicamente. Si el usuario del sistema decide que más de 250 char son suficientes, debe la aplicación validar en el input esta longitud, antes de aceptar entradas.